# get number of sub-folders older than X days

Tags: powershell, directory

im using the following command `$(ls C:\temp).LastWriteTime` which results in a number of folders on my computer, and I can see that there are 2 folders older the X days. However, when I pipe out the results to get last write time older than x days, the results are zero. What am I doing wrong here? The full script looks like this:

```
$(ls c:\temp).LastWriteTime | 
Where{$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)}
Measure-Object |
  select -Expand Count
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using -ge and it should be -le

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp\" -Directory -recurse| where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $(get-date).Adddays(-2)} | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
```